# spring data jdbc get the next value sequence from Oracle?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

In JPA is simple to get the next value from DB with the @Generated etc.

In spring data JDBC working with autogenerated DB IDs is simple/natural.

But how about working with PKs/Ids that are not auto generated like in Oracle Sequence?

Comment: Please explain more. Do you want to use a oracle sequence as primary key in your JPA entity ?

Comment: It is not JPA as you see, it is spring data JDBC. In JPA as I said in the question, it is simple. You add @Gnerated and problems solved.